# One way replication for demo site using MS SQL

Tags: sql-server, merge, transactions, replication

I've been tasked with providing data from our live server to a demo site, so that our sales team can demonstrate the system with the most up to date data available, but not show their changes on our live site.

The data on live does not change often during the day after an initial load of additional data,  but I am worried about conflicts if a data row on demo is changed in a table that is subsequently changed on live and replicated.

Looking at merge replication, a fresh database could be provided, say once per day, but the length of time to replicate could be excessive and, as sometimes our main data feeds to our live data is late, we would need to re-run the merge.

Looking at transactional with updatable subscription, conflicts may occur (also, I do believe that Microsoft are reserving the right to drop this method)

My question is, is there a form of merge replication, that only updates changes, rather than updating the whole database, but allows the subscriber to be used and changed as required?

Comment: If you're in a demo environment, you shouldn't be replicating the live data at all, you should be creating demo data for the demo environment. That not only keeps your real data secure (you do not want your sales reps showing **real** customer data in a demo) but also means you can cater your demonstration data to display all the functionality your system uses, without having to find clients that fulfil those requirements.

Comment: Thank you, and point taken, but in this instance, our CEO and his team want to show his customers their real data in demonstrations as he sells his projects based on the 'what If' scenario based on manipulating their actual data and viewing real time results.

Comment: To be blunt, CEO's shouldn't be making decisions like this. *How* IT implements something is up to IT, and the IT department should also be telling CEOs what they (the IT department) shouldn't be doing. For most regulatory bodies (that your business should be adhering to) using real data in demo/dev environments is a big no no.

Comment: I think that your opinions may be correct, but entirely irrelevant in this case. Is anyone able to help me understand a way to perform the replication I am hoping to achieve?